# Handling node joining docker swarm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, avahi

I was just thinking a way to ease the node-join functionality in `docker swarm` (maybe same can be applied to K8 and other)

Just need your input on this, this will help to remove the dependency of copying the long token with IP and ease the process.

Can we advertise the manager node using `avahi` or some other tool and give it a name, for example, `swarmDemo`, and then in the worker node using `swarmDemo` we can fetch the join token and manager IP which will help to add the node to the swarm.

Please suggest if you have done something similar or you have any other idea?

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you are trying to do? Thx.

Comment: I am trying to create common bash script which will do all the stuffs internally. from Manager if I run `./cluster-mgr init clstr1` it will initialize the swarm and advertise the token and IP to other networks by the name `clstr1` (using avahi or any other channel ) and in the worker node if I run the command `'./cluster-mgr join clstr1` it will fetch the token using browse option and internally runs the docker swarm join command.

this is to ease the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use avahi service to advertise ip, join token and then from the worker node can use that to join to the swarm :)